# Read specific values from two tables with single result - mysql

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have two tables say Listings and Catalog_Options

## Listings

```
listing_id
catalog_option_1
catalog_option_2
catalog_option_3
```

## Catalog_Options

```
id
value
```

Here `catalog_option_1, catalog_option_2, catalog_option_3` contains id that are mapped to Catalog_Options table's id. I want to read value for all 3 and display it in one row for listing_id say list_1

Comment: you should really improve the design of your tables... its bad practice to store a id inside a string

Comment: It is not string it is numeric

Comment: string `catalog_option_1` => `1`  id from Catalog_Options table that is what you said

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
 SELECT * FROM `catalog_options` 
 where id in
 (SELECT catalog_option_1 FROM `listings` 
 union
 SELECT catalog_option_2 FROM `listings`
 union
 SELECT catalog_option_3 FROM `listings`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT l.listing_id,c1.value as ca1,c2.value as ca2,c3.value as ca3 FROM listing l
   JOIN catalog_option c1 on c1.id = l.catalog_option_1
   JOIN catalog_option c2 on c2.id = l.catalog_option_2
   JOIN catalog_option c3 on c3.id = l.catalog_option_3;
```

Comment: your query is giving wrong answer                                      listing_id ca1  ca2 ca3
1          20   25  50
2          60   110 75 i don't know the reason but it is

Comment: Please explain whats wrong in it, as i tried it in sqlfiddle and it given me right answer..

Comment: check my soln provided below, that is what needed i think

Comment: @DharmeshPatel your query returns me only those records where all the options are available i.e. catalog_options_1,2,3. I want all records whether option1,2,3 or none is available and want to narrow search using listing id.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly want you need try this:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(l.listing_id),
    GROUP_CONCAT(c.value)
FROM
    Listings l
LEFT JOIN Catalog_Options c
    ON c.id = RIGHT(l.listing_id,1)
```